# What is the auto-correct view in android?

Tags: android, android-studio

This is a requirement that i have to do for an app.

At runtime,switching between landscape and portrait the background color should change from green to blue.

### Choose an appropriate API level to permit rotation to auto-correct the view.

I already did the background color change,based on rotation but i don't understand this part."Choose an appropriate API level to permit rotation to auto-correct the view."
Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: No idea. That's probably a pretty old assignment, though, so it's possible that very early versions of Android didn't work with rotation properly. Set your `minSdkVersion` to 21 and you won't have issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with any API level.  Just create a colors.xml file with the color you want, and make a landscape override which sets the landscape color.  Use the color you create in colors.xml for the background color in your layout